# What is the REGEXP php syntax to change LastName, Firstname to FirstName LastName?

Tags: php, regex, string

I would like to change the order of names from Last, First to First Last.  I don't know the REGEXP and the php syntax for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use:

```
$name = "Lastname, Firstname";
$names = explode(", ", $name);
$name = $names[1] . " " . $names[0];
```

Comment: To a noobie, something that works seems like magic.   Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
return preg_replace('/^([^,]*),\s*(.*)$/', '$2 $1', $theString);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hate regular expressions.. You could always do something like

```
implode(' ',array_reverse(explode(' ,',$string)))
```

But I'm probably only suggesting that because it's the more intuitive way in Ruby, which I've recently dropped php for :)